# Getting error 'ORA-00976: Specified pseudocolumn or operator not allowed here' in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to run a code which generates sample data and am getting the following errors:
ORA-00976: Specified pseudocolumn or operator not allowed here.
ORA-06512: at line 11
I believe rownum is causing this error however, without it I don't know how to create an unique ID. uploads_seq.next does not seem to work either

```
DECLARE
  v_counter INTEGER := 0;
  v_num_rows INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT start_date, id FROM batch)
  LOOP
    v_num_rows := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 10);
    WHILE v_counter < v_num_rows
    LOOP
        v_counter := v_counter + 1;
        INSERT INTO uploads (id, id_batch, file_name, upload_date, ingested)
        VALUES (rownum + 4000, i.id, 'Batch', i.start_date, 'Y');
    END LOOP;
    v_counter := 0;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: "uploads_seq.next does not seem to work either" - true, but UPLOADS_SEQ.NEXTVAL should.

Comment: What do you expect `rownum` to mean in this context - rather than in a `select`? Did you mean to refer to `v_counter` there? And if you want a unique ID, why not use an identity column, or a plain sequence - does `uploads_seq` exist?

Comment: @Littlefoot that's what I meant oops. I get an error stating sequence does not exist.

Comment: @AlexPoole uploads_seq does not exist. I do intend to use it to create an unique ID

Comment: First you have to **create that sequence**, e.g. CREATE SEQUENCE UPLOADS_SEQ

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE uploads__id__seq START WITH 4001;
```

Then you can perform the insert in a single statement (without the need for PL/SQL or loops):

```sql
INSERT INTO uploads (id, id_batch, file_name, upload_date, ingested)
SELECT uploads__id__seq.NEXTVAL,
       b.id,
       'Batch',
       b.start_date,
       'Y'
FROM   (
         SELECT start_date,
                id,
                FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 11)) AS num_rows
         FROM   batch
         WHERE  ROWNUM > 0 -- Force the sub-query to be materialized.
       ) b
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL AS rn
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= b.num_rows
       );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-9BVHYCR)